# Symfony, замедляют ли связи сущностей работу?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2

Давно мучает один вопрос, замедляют ли связи сущностей в symfony (ManyToMany, ManyToOne и т.д.) работу всего сайта, т.е. как они работают, данные по связям изначально загружаются при формировании сущности, или подтягиваются только при вызове get еров? Т.е. что если в каких-то частях приложения связи используются, а в других частях те же связи не нужны, и тогда же получается что просто загружаются лишние данные? + как они себя ведут в twig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы задаете очень абстрактный вопрос, если у вас установлены связи в БД, ну и что, если вы их не запрашиваете, то они и не тянутся, то есть, всё сводится к `запросу`.

Если говорить о запросах в БД, то можно предположить, что в `symfony` все запросы у вас через `queryBuilder` построены, в таком случае, если вы еще бездумно используете join-ы, то это может внушительно притормозить работу вашего сайта.

Вывод, все зависит от составленного вами запроса к базе данных, если он грамотен и лаконичен, то проблем быть не должно.

Comment: У symfony очень хорошая дока + лучшие практики нужно, а не можно прочитать, там все популярным языком описано. 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Связи к symfony вообще никого отношения не имеют
2. Изучите дебаг приложения своего и вы обнаружите что больше всего времени скрипт проводит в ожидании ответа от базы данных
3. Нужны или нет данные в той или иной ситуации вы и решаете, если они не нужны - не запрашивайте их...

Comment: Т.е. все связи которые указаны в сущности загружаются сразу при формировании сущности, не по отдельности при вызове определенных геттеров?

Comment: @Kirill, Вам стоит пройти в документацию доктрины, там все детально описано